# What is the idiomatic way to write this function (which might normally be called filterA)?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I am going through [this](https://github.com/bitemyapp/fp-course) course.

There is a section for `Applicative` and I am being asked to implement a function with the following behaviour and type

```
-- | Filter a list with a predicate that produces an effect.
--
-- >>> filtering (ExactlyOne . even) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. Nil)
-- ExactlyOne [4,6]
--
-- >>> filtering (\a -> if a > 13 then Empty else Full (a <= 7)) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. Nil)
-- Full [4,5,6]
--
-- >>> filtering (\a -> if a > 13 then Empty else Full (a <= 7)) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. 7 :. 8 :. 9 :. Nil)
-- Full [4,5,6,7]
--
-- >>> filtering (\a -> if a > 13 then Empty else Full (a <= 7)) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. 13 :. 14 :. Nil)
-- Empty
--
-- >>> filtering (>) (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. 7 :. 8 :. 9 :. 10 :. 11 :. 12 :. Nil) 8
-- [9,10,11,12]
--
-- >>> filtering (const $ True :. True :.  Nil) (1 :. 2 :. 3 :. Nil)
-- [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
filtering :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)
```

I have come up with the following implementation, which satifies all the requirements

```
filtering f as =
  let x = sequence (f `map` as)
      y = zip as <$> x
      z = filter snd <$> y
   in map fst <$> z
```

but it feels a bit "round about" to me, and I can't think of a more direct way to do it.

Note: I have expanded into `x, y, z` because it makes it easier (for me) to follow what is happening, and whilst I realize I could express it all on a single line, I do not consider that to be more 'direct' and thus not an answer to my question.

Note 2: This course appears to be building up common type classes from fundamental pieces. We started with a custom implementation of `List` followed by `Functor` and now `Applicative`, so I can only use concepts from these classes. I cannot use anything from `Monad` yet.

Comment: Side note: the *witherable* library indeed calls (a generalised version of) it [`filterA`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.3.1/docs/Data-Witherable.html#v:filterA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first idea would be to start with plain `filter`:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> List a -> List a
filter _ Nil = Nil
filter f (x :. xs) =
    let b = f x
        ys = filter f xs
    in
    if b then x :. ys else ys
```

... and try to extend it to `Applicative`:

```
filtering :: (Applicative f) => (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)
filtering _ Nil = pure Nil
filtering f (x :. xs) =
    let b = f x
        ys = filtering f xs
    in
    if b then x :. ys else ys
```

There are two issues with this attempt: `f x` is an `f Bool`, not a `Bool`, so `if b then ...` is a type error, and `filtering f xs` is an `f (List a)`, not a `List a`, so `x :. ys` is a type error.

We can fix those problems by using `lift2 :: (Applicative f) => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`:

```
filtering f (x :. xs) =
    lift2 (\b ys -> if b then x :. ys else ys) (f x) (filtering f xs)
```

`lift2` lets us locally extract a `Bool` and a `List a` from `f x` and `filtering f xs`, respectively; or more correctly, we've wrapped our `if ... then ... else` computation in a function, which `lift2` then pushes into `f`.

Alternatively we could use `<$>` and `<*>` directly:

```
filtering f (x :. xs) =
    (\b ys -> if b then x :. ys else ys) <$> f x <*> filtering f xs
```

Or write our helper function slightly differently:

```
filtering f (x :. xs) =
    (\b -> if b then (x :.) else id) <$> f x <*> filtering f xs
```

Comment: Great answer! For all those reading this who aren't familiar with this course, the operator (:.) on the custom List type, is equivalent to the (:) operator on the stock List type.

Comment: @ChechyLevas And `lift2` is `liftA2` from `Control.Applicative`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation in terms of `foldr` (and written using *base* types and functions). I'm fairly sure it is equivalent to [melpomene's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56417298/2751851).

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
import Data.Bool (bool)

filterA :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> [a] -> f [a]
filterA f = foldr (\x xs -> liftA2 (++) (bool [] [x] <$> f x) xs) (pure [])
```

A few details worth noting:

- `bool y x b` is pointfree-friendly slang for `if b then x else y`.
- Using `(++)` instead of `(:)` to add the elements is fine since we are doing it to the front of the list.
- `xs` isn't literally a list -- it has type `f [a]`.

A demonstration:

```
GHCi> filterA (\x -> print x *> pure (x > 5)) [1..10]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
[6,7,8,9,10]
```

---

Here is a different take, inspired by your original solution (note that `sequence (map f xs)` is the same as `traverse f xs`):

```
filterA :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> [a] -> f [a]
filterA f = fmap concat . traverse (\x -> bool [] [x] <$> f x)
```

(`bool Nothing (Just x)` and `catMaybes` from `Data.Maybe` instead of `bool [] [x]` and `concat` would also work.)

Note that this solution requires an additional pass through the list(s) because `traverse` is not strong enough to implement filtering. That is why `filter`, `catMaybes`, `filterA` and friends require [different classes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.3.1/docs/Data-Witherable.html) if they are to be generalised.